# Pass argument with path to command line executable with php

Tags: php, c++, xcode, executable

I have a simple hello world command line application which I a trying to execute via php but I don't know how to switch to the debug folder of the application and then run the executable. So far I have tried using `popen` to move the location where the terminal is, however it seems incorrect in the way I have done it and then used `exec` to execute the command.

Heres my PHP file:

```
<?php
$loc = '/Users/dave/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloWorld-akuofooecqboeybtsfalcrelvfjt/Build/Products/Debug';
$argv = "./HelloWorld j";
popen($loc, 'r');
echo exec($argv);
```

And heres my c++ command line program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if( argc < 2 )
    { printf("Please enter a value \n");
        return -1;
    }
    std::cout << argv[1]<<"\n";
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The directory where the debug folder for this is `/Users/dave/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloWorld-akuofooecqboeybtsfalcrelvfjt/Build/Products/Debug` and to execute this I used `./HelloWorld x` (slight note how would this work if the `HelloWorld` application had a space?)

Everything works fine when I do run this from the terminal, so it is not a problem with the c++ file.

So can someone please tell me how can I execute this application from php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in php you can execute a command via `system()` function :

```
system('YOUR COMMAND - FOR EXAMPLE ./HelloWorld (in your path)');
```

to get the result you can put it into an variable.

```
$test=system("some command");
var_dump($test);
```

In your case:

```
system('PATH/HelloWorld j'); // runs your HelloWorld executable file
```

Another solution is using `shell_exec()` function. As php.net example:

```
$output = shell_exec('ls -lart');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

each one has its own advantages and disadvantages. You can read more about mentioned functions in php.net/following links:

[shell_exec — Execute command via shell and return the complete output as a string](https://www.php.net/shell_exec)

[system — Execute an external program and display the output](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)

Comment: How would this work? If the system is not used while I am not in the correct directory it would not give me an answer.

Comment: You must put your executable application into a pre-defined directory. For example in your PHP application's directory. Does its directory change dynamically?

Comment: You can easily do: system('PATH/HelloWorld j')

Comment: No it doesn't however it is in a directory that is created by `Xcode` and not by me so it can be problematic to move the executable to my php directory which is in a `MAMP htdocs` file.

Comment: The path worked thank you, I didnt know you can execute an executable like that. If you could add that to your answer that would be great for others wanting to know the answer.

Comment: You're welcome dear, But be aware that some servers close the system function due to security reasons.